# jquery loaded html content is missing variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, velocity

I'm using jquery's .load() to load the response from a servlet to a div. However, the loaded div is printing out html content and missing all the values from velocity template. When I access the servlet directly from the browser, the output is as expected. I don't know what I'm missing, please help me. Below is the contents of Servlet where it renders HTML using velocity template:

```
templateRenderer.render(VELOCITY_TEMPLATE, context, response.getWriter());
```

The contents of JS file responsible for requesting the servlet is here:

```
    AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
    AJS.$('#form').submit(function() {

        AJS.$.ajax({
            url : AJS.params.baseURL + "/plugins/servlet/getissues",
            type : 'GET',
            datatype : 'html',
            success : function(response) {
                document.getElementById("#form").reset();

                AJS.$('#result').load(response);
                alert("Hello " + response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The response I'm getting is below:

```
<div class="module">
 <div class="mod-content">
    <form class="aui" id="form" >               
        <input type="hidden" id="projectKey" name="projectKey" value=$project.getKey() />
        <label class="selectLabels" for="issuetype">Issue Type: </label>
        <select class="select" id="issuetype" name="issuetype" form="form">
                <option value="">-All-</option>
        </select>

        <label class="selectLabels" for="component">Component: </label>
        <select class="select" id="component" name="component" form="form">
                <option value="">-All-</option>
        </select>

        <label class="selectLabels" for="version">Affected Version:    </label>                                                 
        <select class="select" id="version" name="version" form="form">
                <option value="">-All-</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>         
    </form>         
<div id="result" class="aui">
    <!--The values generated using velocity template should be shown here-->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you  share the response your are getting ?

Comment: Hi @user2118422, I edited the question with response.